# How to set ContextMenu in QTabWidget for pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I want to set the Context Menu above QTabWidget, so I inherited QTabBar to override the mousePressEvent function, and then set setTabBar() in QTabWidget, although this can be achieved, but the self.setTabsClosable(True) method seems to be invalid, I can't see the Tab Closed button on TabBar.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class TabBar(QTabBar):
    middleClicked = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(QTabBar, self).__init__()
        self.previousMiddleIndex = -1
        # self.setTabsClosable(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        if mouseEvent.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            print("Context_menu is OK.")
        QTabBar.mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent)


class TabDemo(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tbar = TabBar()
        self.setTabBar(self.tbar)
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab 1")
        self.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab 2")
        self.tab1UI()
        self.tab2UI()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tab case")
        self.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.setTabsClosable(True)

    def tab1UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow("name", QLineEdit())
        self.setTabText(0, "contact")
        self.tab1.setLayout(layout)

    def tab2UI(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        sex = QHBoxLayout()
        sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("man"))
        sex.addWidget(QRadioButton("woman"))
        self.tab2.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = TabDemo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You're asking (at least, in the title) how to set a context menu, but in the question you are asking something that's completely unrelated. What is your actual problem with your code? I can see both the context menu call when the mouse button is clicked *and* the close buttons on each tab.

Comment: I set the TabBar(), but I can't see the close button on the tabbar.

Comment: Does the close button appear if you use the default QTabBar? What OS and version are you using?

Comment: Yes, Default QTabBar is appear, I am using python 3.7,IOS 10.14.5, PyQt5 5.13.1

Comment: Ok, as I was afraid of. I've had a similar problem while setting custom QTabBar on MacOs (but I hoped that that was solved in latest PyQt5 releases): it seems that when setting custom tab bars the close button is not recreated again. Unfortunally I can't test PyQt5 on MacOs, but I believe that the solution might be the same. I'll post a possible answer in the next hours, keep an eye on your notifications.

Comment: Can you try if any of these work? `self.tabBar().tabButton(0, self.tabBar().RightSide).setVisible(True)` or, alternatively, `self.tabBar().tabButton(0, self.tabBar().LeftSide).setVisible(True)`

Comment: self.tabBar().tabButton(0, self.tabBar() and self.tabBar().tabButton(0, self.tabBar().LeftSide) is None

Comment: TabBar looks like no tabButton QWidget.

Comment: I forgot: have you tried to create the QTabBar with the tabwidget as a parent? Right now you create it without any parent, but that might be necessary for some system/styling capabilities. Just add the parent argument to the `def __init__` and the `super.__init__`, then create it with `self.tbar = TabBar(self)`.

Comment: Oh! It's work fine.Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: Good! I creted an answer to better clarify it, remember to mark it as accepted :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some complex QWidgets that can be customized by setting alternate child widgets sometimes require those children to be initialized with the parent they will be added to; some examples include the scroll bars of QAbstractScrollArea descendants (QTextEdit, QGraphicsView, etc), headers for item views, views of QComboBox, and, obviously, tab bar of QTabWidget.

While in most cases that's not mandatory, it is better to keep that in mind, as some particular (and in some cases, platform dependant) configuration is automatically added to the child widget according to the state of what will become its parent.
That's the case for setting an alternate QTabBar for a QTabWidget, specifically on MacOs (I suppose that's due to some platform issues about how tab widgets are dealt with on this platform).

This will solve the issue:

```
class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QTabBar, self).__init__(parent)

class TabDemo(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tbar = TabBar(self)
        self.setTabBar(self.tbar)
        self.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.setTabsClosable(True)
```

There is a [reported bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-64269) exactly about this; it's still marked as unresolved, but I think that's just because (as the user reporting it remarks) setting the parent solves the issue.